# Find the regular expression for the language on E={a,b}

Tags: regex, computer-science, regular-language, dfa, nfa

L = w : (na(w) - nb(w)) mod 3 /= 0

How can I go about finding the regular expression for this language?

I understand that it means that the number of As minus the number of Bs cannot be a multiple of 3. So a - b cannot be 3,6,9,12, etc.

But I am still having trouble putting it into a regular expression. I tried first making it a DFA or NFA but I couldn't do that either.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go about it by dividing the list of words on {a,b} into three cases:

- L1 =  w : (na(w) - nb(w)) mod 3 = 1
- L2 =  w : (na(w) - nb(w)) mod 3 = 2
- L3 =  w : (na(w) - nb(w)) mod 3 = 3

L is then `L1 U L2`, and you should be able to create expressions relating L1, L2, and L3. You should then be able to eliminate things and end up with a regular expression on {a,b}.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use that to figure out my answer. Is L3 suppose to be "L3 = w : (na(w) - nb(w)) mod 3 = 0" though?

Comment: Yes, that's a typo. I'll fix it. Good luck.