# How to write this automaton

Tags: automata, dfa, deterministic, automaton

I am trying to solve some problems in An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata, by Peter Linz.
In Section 2.1 (Deterministic Finite Acceptors), I cannot write the automaton and need help to solve it.

Question 17-(f), Chapter 2:

```
L = {w : |na(W) - nb(W)| % 3 < 2}
```

`na` is the number of `a` characters in the word, 
`nb` is the number of `b` characters in the word.

I have solution but I don't know how to draw it here.

Comment: [Find the regular expression for the language on `E = {a,b}`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214574/find-the-regular-expression-for-the-language-on-e-a-b)

Comment: Look at Q7.(d) it is solved at back. It does help.

Answer (score 0):

So we have 3 states: R0, R1, R2, which mean the remainders of the division by 3.
Then we have our automaton with R0 the start state:

```
R0(a) -> R1
R0(b) -> R2
R1(a) -> R2
R1(b) -> R0
R2(a) -> R0
R2(b) -> R1
```

R0 and R1 are accepting states.